# couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret

Tags: mysql, authentication, kubernetes, deployment

I have the following file that creates a `mysql-secret` for `mysql` deployment pod.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-root-password: MTExMTEx
  mysql-user: YQ==
```

The problem is that, previously I could deploy `mysql` on `Kubernetes` cluster using the secret key created by this command:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal MYSQL_KEY=11111
```

And using `MYSQL_KEY` I could pass it to other `deployment` files like `auth` as you can see below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: auth
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_URI
              value: 'mysql://auth-mysql-srv:3306/users_auth'
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: MYSQL_KEY
```

But now I don't have a key using a `yaml` file to create the secret key and I get the following error because of that:

```
 - deployment/auth-mysql-depl is ready. [3/5 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/mysql: container mysql in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret,}
    - pod/mysql-78bbf5f6f4-vbpkz: container mysql in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret,}
```

How can I add a `key: MY_SQL` property to the `secret.yaml` file or find a way to eliminate it from the other `deployment` files like `auth` that uses it?

If I just eliminate `key: MYSQL_KEY` from auth `deployment` file I get this error:

```
 - The Deployment "auth-depl" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[1].valueFrom.secretKeyRef.key: Required value
```

EDIT: I tried to create the secret before I run `skaffold dev` using `kubectl apply -f mysql-secret.yaml` command and it worked. My question is, how can I say to `skafoold` please run `kubectl apply -f` on `mysql-secret.yaml` file before the other `yaml` files?

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v4beta1
kind: Config
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: auth
    context: auth-service
    sync:
      manual:
      - src: src/**/*.ts
        dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  - image: client
    context: client-service
    sync:
      manual:
      - src: lib/**/*.dart
        dest: .
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  local:
    push: false
manifests:
  rawYaml:
  - ./infra/k8s/*
deploy:
  kubectl: {}
  kubeContext: kind-kind
```

Answer (score 1):

**Common causes of this error :**

1)**ConfigMap is missing**—a ConfigMap stores configuration data as key-value pairs.

**Resolution :** Identify the missing ConfigMap and create it in the namespace, or mount another, existing ConfigMap.

2)**Secret is missing**—a Secret is used to store sensitive information such as credentials.

**Resolution :** Identify the missing Secret and create it in the namespace, or mount another, existing Secret.

***Try below possible solutions :***

**Solution 1:**

The reason is due to when we create secret it regards the whole text as one single string as config.yaml
It does not take username or password as key
To workaround it, we need to get decoded string via base64

```
echo 'test' | base64  --->  dGVzdAo=
```

Then correct yaml file is :

```
apiVersion: v1kind: Secretmetadata:  name:  test-stg-secret
type: Opaque
data:
    username: dGVzdAo=
    password:  dGVzdAo=
```

Please go through [Henry Xie 's blog](https://www.henryxieblogs.com/2019/02/error-couldnt-find-key-username-in.html)  & similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650044/cant-connect-to-mysql-pod-in-kubernetes-when-using-secrets-for-password-access) for more information.

**Solution 2 :**
You need to understand whether a ConfigMap or Secret is missing. Run `kubectl describe pod <podname> -n <namespace>`, you might see the cause of failing.

Run one of these commands to see if the requested ConfigMap or Secret exists in the cluster:

```
<pre”>kubectl get configmap kubectl get secret
```

If the command returns null, the ConfigMap or Secret is indeed missing. Follow these instructions to create the missing object mounted by the failed container: **[create a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) or [create a secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/)**.

If the pod has not started then you can not exec into pod, In this case run `kubectl get pods -o wide` and check in which node the pod is scheduled.

Go to that node and run `docker ps -a` and get the container id desired container and
then check `docker logs -f <container id>`. Note : (you can ssh into the node.)

Please go through [Fixing CreateContainerConfig Error](https://komodor.com/learn/how-to-fix-createcontainerconfigerror-and-createcontainer-errors/) for more information

**Solution 3:** Before the container goes into the Running state it goes through the deployment configuration and validates all the necessary configurations which are needed for the successful deployment of the docker container. During the validation phase it tries to find the `secretKeyRef` with the `name`, `key` but it could not find those secrets available inside the kubernetes cluster leading to `CreateContainerConfigError`.

1)Replicate the error CreateContainerConfigError

2)How to Check the container logs for finding the missing Kubernetes Secret

3)**Create and apply the correct kubernetes secret**

4)Re-run the kubernetes deployment after fixing the kubernetes secret

5)Debugging of the CreateContainerConfigError by looking into the POD logs using the `kubectl describe Pod` command.

Please go through [Solving Error CreateContainerConfig](https://www.datree.io/resources/kubernetes-troubleshooting-fixing-createcontainerconfig-error) for more information.

Comment: The problem was number 3. Please read the `EDIT` part I added to my question.